# Is there a more efficient way to these for loops in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have the following for loops all of which run from 1 to 8. I'm wondering if all of this can be encased in just 1 for loop. The reason it doesn't work at the moment is because if you break from the for loop then it would exit it for all if statements.

```
for i in range(1, 8):
    if Bool1(based on i):
        Action1
    else:
        break

for i in range(1, 8):
    if Bool2(based on i):
        Action2
    else:
        break

for i in range(1, 8):
    if Bool3(based on i):
        Action3
    else:
        break

for i in range(1, 8):
    if Bool4(based on i):
        Action4
    else:
        break

...
```

Comment: Do you really need to break the for looop when the first condition evaluates to `False`? If so, then no, you can't do any better than this.

Comment: Difficult to say, as `based on i` is not valid Python and can be many things. If you can break all of those down to the same form, let's say a function taking `i` as a single param, then you can.

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? Do you want to do this with less code? Or do you mean you want it to run faster?

Comment: Just use `elif`?

Comment: @Ava A single loop with an `if...elif...else` chain will give different behavior in the general case than the OP's code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
tests_and_actions = [
    (Bool1, Action1),
    (Bool2, Action2),
    (Bool3, Action3),
    (Bool4, Action4),
    # ...
]

for test, action in tests_and_actions:
    for i in range(1, 8):
        if test(based on i):
            action()
        else:
            break
```

Comment: This is less code, but not any more efficient run time.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Was the question about efficiency?

Comment: The title says as much.

Comment: @zvone yes, it's in the title

Comment: But less code is already better according to the DRY principle...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Agreed. I would even encapsulate the loop in a reusable function. I'm just pointing out that the OP asked about efficiency.

Comment: This is definitely an inprovement over the OP's code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The title and description are not descriptive enough it may mean "efficient to type". Anyway, there is no way to make code more efficient without knowing what it does. This is generic code.

Comment: @zvone Agreed. I posted a comment to clarify what the OP means by "more efficient". My initial inclination was to take it literally as run-time efficiency, but the OP might mean something different.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: yes but when I see *efficiency* without precision, it can relate to anything, speed, memory, or even code size. On a pure execution time point of view, the best when possible is a looong linear (even if unstructured...) sequence of code.

Comment: @SergeBallesta See my previous comment to zvone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following two conditions:

- The order of execution of the actions does not matter.
- `ActionX` does not have side effects that cause future calls to `BoolY` to give a different result.

The following (while far from beautiful) should work:

```py
# Flags, indicating which part is still relevant
active1 = True
active2 = True
active3 = True
active4 = True

for i in range(1, 8):

    if active1 and Bool1(based on i):
        Action1
    else:
        active1 = False

    if active2 and Bool2(based on i):
        Action2
    else:
        active2 = False

    ...

    # The below is just an optimization to avoid superfluous looping.
    if not active1 and not active2 and not active3 and not active4:
        break
```

Assuming with "more efficient", you mean "faster: One would need to profile the actual use-case to find out which version has the smaller run time.

Comment: This behaves differently than the OP's code.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Ah, you mean because the order of execution of the actions is different? (I've just added a remark about this to my answer.)

Comment: Yes, exactly. The question is phrased in a way that indicates that this may be okay, but since in the general case, the order in which code is executed matters, this should be pointed out for future readers.

Comment: Btw. not just the order. `Action1` may influence the result of `Bool2`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks, you're right of course. Evil side effect. ;-) I'll add a remark about that too.